# How do I create a PDF that does NOT embed the used fonts?

Tags: pdf, fonts, ghostscript

Using MS Word 2010, or a free program, how do I create a pdf that does not include the used font(s)? I need this to test a feature in GhostScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using ghostscript anyway, you can generate the PDF with ghostscript using `-dEmbedAllFonts=false`.